# Regex Redirect Issue (Subfolder Capitalization Issue)

Tags: regex, redirect

First Question Here.

I have looked a the other regex-related questions and tried to apply what was suggested in the answers but I am still having an issue.

**Description**:
In short, I have started a new job with a company that has a pretty significant page duplication issue. Pretty much every page can be loaded in two ways.

```
https://www.domainname.com/en_ca/products/
https://www.domainname.com/en_CA/products/
```

Keep in mind that this applies to ANY URL.

**Current Effort:**

I have set up a regex redirect that goes like this:

```
^www\.domainname\.com/en_ca(.*)

to

https://www.domainname.com/en_CA\1
```

Even in the tool itself, it says that it should work, but when I actually implement the redirect the page just freezes. Doesn't hit a 404 or anything, just kind of loads for forever.

[Picture of the tool's result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlWIJ.png)